# ion-item-options not displaying

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an app using Ionic 3. I have an ion-item-sliding wrapped within an ion-list. I need to show the options when the list item is swiped. I got the color working but the text is not displaying at all. I don't have any css applied to the button at all.

```
<ion-list text-wrap>
      <ion-list-header>
        ...
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item *ngIf="classes?.length === 0">No Data</ion-item>
      <ion-item-group *ngFor="let classObj of classes">
        <ion-item-divider>...</ion-item-divider>
        <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let class of classObj?.classes">
          <ion-item *ngFor="let class of classObj?.classes">
            <ion-grid>
              ...
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item-options side="right">
            <button ion-button color="secondary">
              Change
            </button>
          </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>
      </ion-item-group>
    </ion-list>
```

[image]

I have no idea what went wrong. This happened to both Android and iOS

Comment: Will it show if u remove the color?

Comment: nope. It's the same. I even tried to apply ```style="color: 'red'"``` to the button but its not working

Comment: Can you execute in the terminal `ionic info` I think u are using ionic 4

Comment: I get this
```ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.9.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10```

Comment: Try and add it inside an ion-label

Comment: TBH button doesn't work at all when wrapped inside ```ion-item-options``` I managed to fix it temporarily using ```a``` tag

Comment: Try creating a plunker for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its ok I have found the solution. I mistakenly `*ngFor` both `ion-item-sliding` and `ion-item` hence the slider breaks. I removed `*ngFor` in the `ion-item` and everything is works fine now

Comment: Happened to me too. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to provide small cancel button next to your ion-select, which appears only when the user has already selected something:

```
<ion-label>Options</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="option">
   <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
   <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
</ion-select>

<div *ngIf="option=='m' || option=='f'">
<ion-label> {{option}} </ion-label>
<ion-button  (click)='removeSelection()'>
   <ion-icon name='close'></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```